# PDOException: could not find driver when using phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, phpunit

I am starting to use laravel 4 and I am trying to start using unit tests so I can make my live easier. Well as all of you will guess my development hasn't become easier after trying phpunit tests. The simple tests are well, easy but when the things start to get a bit more complicated  they does not go as I though they will.

The problem is I have conducted simple tests but I get some strange error `PDOException: could not find driver`. I have read a few articles and post on this topic but nothing solved my problem. I have installed `php5-mysql` and when I call `php -m` it says that I have both PDO and pdo_mysql. The actual command I use is `php -m |grep -i "pdo"` and the output is:

```
PDO
pdo_mysql
```

Well I've tried to actualy test PDOException class in the browser. For that purpose I have change the mysql user password to incorrect one and tested what will happen in **artisan server** (called with command `php artisan serve` ---> `http://localhost:8000/`). In the browser everything works as a charm but when I try to call ``phpunit` in the **console** the result is not the same.

I have tried to see if webserver and cli have different configuration files but it turnout that the files are identical. The configuration files that I have compared are:

**for the web server**

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

**for command line**

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

to compare them I user the diff command like so `diff -s /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2`.

The errors look like this:

```
1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
PDOException: could not find driver

/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SQLiteConnector.php:22
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:59
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:47
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:127
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:63
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:167
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:135
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:366
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:93
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:56
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:108
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:96
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:96
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Artisan.php:57
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:208
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:208
/var/www/smlsspd/app/tests/TestCase.php:70
/var/www/smlsspd/app/tests/TestCase.php:70
/var/www/smlsspd/app/tests/TestCase.php:46
phar:///var/www/smlsspd/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:179
phar:///var/www/smlsspd/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:132
```

Can you give me a hint or solution to this problem?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems Laravel using SQLite as database for testing. See the backtrace at line 2:

```
/var/www/smlsspd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SQLiteConnector.php:22
```

But this seems not installed on your system. So I think you need to install the SQLite driver.

Comment: Ok that seem to be a problem because I really don't have SQLite PDO driver installed. I'll test things out later.

Comment: I finaly got home and tested things out. It seems like I don't read all the error messages. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using sqlite for testing you will need php sqlite drivers

For Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In ubuntu 16.04 there is no `php5-sqlite`

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have php 7.1 what should be expected?

Answer (score 8):

If you are occupying SqLite you have to enter php.init and uncomment this line.

```
;extension = pdo_sqlite
```

Comment: I did but still showing "$ php artisan migrate --env=testing
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0". My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Apart uncomment this line in php.unit
extension = pdo_sqlite
In your phpunit.xml file you have to have these two lines
<server name = "DB_CONNECTION" value = "sqlite" />
<server name = "DB_DATABASE" value = ": memory:" />

Answer (score 4):

On Windows i had to activate `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll` in php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

For those using [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead), make sure you're running `phpunit` from *within* Homestead and not on your local machine! You can [SSH into it](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#connecting-via-ssh) with `vagrant ssh`.

As others have mentioned, it requires SQLite and thus running it within your virtual machine ensures that's available to your test.

Answer (score 2):

php7.0-sqlite no longer works use php7.1-sqlite

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I've run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite` but got those errors: `E: Unable to locate package php7.1-sqlite
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-sqlite'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-sqlite'`

Comment: try sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3

Comment: that sneaky `3` I missed, in any case I did `apt-cache search php7.1-sqlite3` and got no search results, and same for `php7.1-sqlite` only `php7.0-sqlite` returns `php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP`, I may be missing required ppa (I use Ubuntu subsystem on Windows)

Answer (score 2):

first, install SQLite for PHP with
`sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`

then check your `php.ini` and make sure the below line is uncommented

```
;extension = pdo_sqlite
```

then if you are using apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`

or if you are using Nginx

`sudo service nginx restart`

---

note: if you don't know where is your php.ini path use `php -i |grep php.ini` command

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, in `phpunit.xml` file, just set `"DB_CONNECTION"` and `"DB_DATABASE"` values. Since I was using mysql (not sqlite), I changed them like this:

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="db_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using mysql, add this line in phpunit.xml:

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
```

Then install the mysql package in php

```
$ apt-get install php-mysql
```

Try again :)